# Magento website suddenly has 'No data received' Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, apache, magento, ubuntu

We have Magento running on an eCommerce website an the last few days it seems that some really important pages are simply not loading!

Majority of the pageson the site load fine however if a user is "logged in" and they try to access the cart checkout page, by far the most important page, they receive this very nasty message shown below in the image...

[image]

As far as I know, no changes to code have been made the last few days so I do not even know where to look at this point for a solution.

A Google search shows that many people had had this problem before, mostly on WOrdPress sites but there never is a solution posted!

I am hoping someone can point us in the right direction as this is a major problem on this site right now if a user cannot checkout.

The other page that i noticed it is happening on is the page to create a new user account, once you fill the form out and hit submit, it shows the page shown in image as well.

We are running Apache on Ubuntu 12  believe.  We also have Varnish Cache if that means anything.

Please help!

Also here is what I get for the same page in FireFox...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the usual stuff? Turning off the cache? Clearing the  cache? Checking access and error logs?

Comment: @Darren Yes have tried all that sort of stuff...my boss has been talking to Rackspace the past hour though and I believe they have it resolved or somewhat so perhaps some sort of server level stuff was changed on their part.  When I find out I might update the post just in case it helps someone else in future.

Comment: Sweet! Unrelated question - what is rackspace like? We're actually looking at potentially using them in the near future.

Comment: We are moving away from them, they are good, just extremely overpriced IMO

Comment: Just check is this is an issues because of SSL certificate.Uplaod a simple hello.php and try to get that page using https

Comment: @SatishMantri The thing was, 95% of the site worked fine, it was just like 2-3 pages that we noticed and only when a POST was occurring I believe...I think my boss and/or Rackspace got it resolved but I haven't spoken to them yet as it;s middle of the night....I will update when I find out what the issue was

Comment: Check if there is any limitation on post size.

Comment: UPDATE:  Problem was corrupt data in PHP APC Cache!

Comment: Appreciate your efforts on updating with exact reason.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by others, try flushing the [APC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache_.28APC.29) Opcode cache.

You can do that by adding the following lines to your *magento/index.php* right at the top of the file to [clear the cache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php)

```
apc_clear_cache();
apc_clear_cache('user');
```

**WARNING**

As one cause of the problem can be a corrupted Opcode cache you should only use this **once** (add the code, then call the page) and **comment it out afterwards**, otherwise you won't have any performance improvements by the APC, maybe even a degrading performance as the cache will be filled with every page call.

So, add the code, call the page, then comment the code out. (if it didn't work, comment it out and search for another solution, DON'T leave the code in the index.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you Google for this problem, you will find 100 different answers as it seems many different things can cause this error.

We got ours fixed now and our problem was corruption in PHP's APC Cache.

Flushing APC Cache solved all our problems, perhaps this will help someone someday, it;s another of the 100 things to check!

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the APC Opcode cache resolved this error for me

Comment: How you cleared  APC Opcode cache. May i know how you did that?