# Fatal error when trying to clear APC cache using index.php

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error, apc

i am facing this problem in magento site:

[Magento website suddenly has 'No data received' Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540187/magento-website-suddenly-has-no-data-received-error-code-err-empty-response)

so i tried solution provided by @Larzen in that link

but i am getting following error at the end of the frontend and backend :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache() in /var/www/html/site/index.php on line 92
```

so is there any way to clear APC cache through index.php file or how we can do this from server side.

Comment: you have APC installed in your server?
Run a php script containing the following:
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
and search for "APC". See what it says.

Comment: APc is not installed than there is no need to clear apc cache right ? or is we have to install apc for fixing the problem in that link

Comment: post your comment as answer